# Math to calculate booking period

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, geometry

I need some help plotting time on my chart. I have a grid with 24 boxes going across horizontally on my html page. Each box represents an hour and has a defined width of 28px in my spreadsheet. The first box starts at 12AM and then it goes all the way through to 11PM(24 hour day).

What I now need to do is plot my items on the grid, the only issue is I cant figure out the maths to work out where the left position should start from and how wide it should be. The left position in my code is based on a percentage, 0% being the start of 12AM. The width is based in pixels. Anyone out there who can show me the way?

so lets say I have the following items, what would the left position (%) and width (px) be for each. I just need the formula really as I could work out how to code it and inject it on my grid

```
Name, StartTime, EndTime
Item 1, 9:55, 14:55
Item 2, 16:00, 17:45
Item 2, 18:10, 19:55
```

Comment: I'd suggest using javascript for something like this

Comment: If you just want the formula I think it might be more appropriate to tag it with something like "algorithm" or "geometry"?

Comment: I would convert everything to "minutes of the day", where a day goes from minute 0 to 1440 and use that to position your "booking block".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `n = 24` boxes, width `w = 28`px each. The time can be represented by `h` hours and `m` minutes.

Essentially you just want to figure out a start and end for each box, and you can convert that to a pixel width, and convert *that* to a percentage.

1. `h + m/60` will give you fractional hours.  Multiply by the width to get the pixel location of a time: `(h + m/60)*w`. (Quick sanity check: 1:30 should be at 1 and a half widths, or 42 pixels.)
2. Do this for both times, now you have `start_px` and `end_px`. This lets you calculate a `width = end_px - start_px`.
3. Now you can convert that into a percentage: `width_percent = width / total_width * 100 = width / (w * n) * 100`

So your final formula should look like:

```
start_px = (start_h + start_m/60)*w
end_px = (end_h + end_m/60)*w
width_percent = (end_px - start_px) / (w * n) * 100
```

**Edit:** Here's a quick-and-dirty Python 2 script (just what I had handy) to run some examples.

```
def find_width(start_h, start_m, end_h, end_m, n, w):
    start_px = (start_h + start_m/60.)*w
    end_px = (end_h + end_m/60.)*w
    width_percent = (end_px - start_px)/(w*n)*100
    print "%d:%02d-%d:%02d Spans from %dpx to %dpx, or %.2f%%"%(start_h, start_m, end_h, end_m, start_px, end_px, width_percent)

n = 24 # 24 hours
w = 10 # width of 10, easier to check math

# entire day - should be 240 px or 100%
find_width(0,0, 24,0, n,w)

# half day - should be 50%
find_width(0,0, 12,0, n,w)

# try starting from not-zero
find_width(4,0, 16,0, n,w)
find_width(4,30, 5,30, n,w)

# try non-zero minutes
find_width(4,30, 16,30, n,w)

# try less than an hour
find_width(4,30, 5,00, n,w)
find_width(4,30, 4,45, n,w)
```

This outputs:

```
0:00-24:00 Spans from 0px to 240px, or 100.00%
0:00-12:00 Spans from 0px to 120px, or 50.00%
4:00-16:00 Spans from 40px to 160px, or 50.00%
4:30-5:30 Spans from 45px to 55px, or 4.17%
4:30-16:30 Spans from 45px to 165px, or 50.00%
4:30-5:00 Spans from 45px to 50px, or 2.08%
4:30-4:45 Spans from 45px to 47px, or 1.04%
```